# Bluemix LiveSync for Node.js javascript files

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a Node.js project working with an html file and two .js files.

The first .js file loads the second one and uses functions defined in it.

Main file. App.js

```
var functions = require('./functions');
functions.test();
```

Functions file. functions.js

```
module.exports = 
{
  test: function () 
  {
     console.log("Into test Function 2");
  }
};
```

Live edit is enabled.

If I make changes to the .html page in the bl log I see the file being updated and if I reload the html in the browser I see the change.

But if I make changes to any of the .js files although the files are also uploaded the changes are not being reflected on runtime. I have to stop and start the application to those changes to take effect.

Does Live Sync only applies for static files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Live Sync is syncing all files, but for server side javascript file updates, node needs to restart for it to pick up the changes. There is a quick restart button right next to the `Live Sync` option. The restart should only take a couple of seconds.

You can use the combination of Live Sync AND nodemon (Monitor for any changes in your node.js application and automatically restart the server). You would have to modify the start command to nodemon.

Comment: How do I use nodemon on Bluemix? I have edited package.json and modified the "script" parametor:  "scripts": {"start": "nodemon app.js"}. Then when I try to start the application in Bluemix I get the error: NodejsStarterApp@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
nodemon app.js
nodemon: not found

Comment: @Jxadro try adding also nodemon module to dependencies section of package.json file, so it should be installed when the runtime resolves dependencies before executing the command.

Comment: Hi.Thank you, I thought that was only for modules used in the javascript code. Now it starts but it seems nodemod does not detect the changes or does not restart the apps. Added: "dependencies": {"nodemon": "1.5.x"}. Now in the logs I see: OUT > nodemon app.js
OUT 18 Sep 09:10:39 - ?[33m[nodemon] v1.5.1?[39m
OUT 18 Sep 09:10:39 - ?[33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`?[39m
OUT 18 Sep 09:10:39 - ?[33m[nodemon] watching: *.*?[39m
OUT 18 Sep 09:10:39 - ?[32m[nodemon] starting `node app.js`?[39m But after bl upload the file changed it does not restart node. I only see those traces once.